# Communicating between mobile devices over a local network

Tags: android, ios

I'm a complete newbie with regards to developing for Android, and for starters I'm trying to develop a simple card game that can be played multiplayer over a local network. I'm having trouble finding a starting point for how I would go about this, I can find plenty of things for communicating across the internet but not having much luck seeing how you communicate directly between two devices over a LAN.

It's a major part of my plan for this app that it be multi-platform and that iOS devices and Android devices can play against each other, so I'm looking for a method that supports this. I know it's possible as I can see there are other apps that have this functionality.

I don't need a detailed implementation (although the more help the better!) but if anyone could just point me in the right direction for how to go about something like this, I'd be really grateful.

Comment: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/socket-core/android-socket-example/

Comment: A fairly new API called [Android Nearby](https://developers.google.com/nearby) abstracts the transmission process and automatically switches to the most appropriate communication medium on the fly, when needed

Answer (score 1):

I think u need a connection peer to peer, android implements Wifi Direct

Look android dev site. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html

Answer (score 0):

For a card game I recommend using client-server. 
Electrotank is a good server that provides a framework that helps you create a game of this type, with rooms, chat, friends list and connect to Android and iOS. U can write server plugins in Java.
http://www.electrotank.com/es5.html.
Another good server solution is SmartFox.

Or you can create a turn-based game, creating a database to save data and a counter on each client, where you will limit the time for each move, from this time you send data to the server and your opponent query this data the server.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question, I don't think these are quite what I'm looking for as I want something that can communicate directly between devices with no need for a server installed on a pc etc, but I will look into these further, cheers!

Comment: Without a servers and local use bluetooth, small bandwidth, but for a card game works fine. Using bluetooth u can easy discover new devices around.

Answer (score 0):

I was working on the exact same thing. You'll want to use sockets to open up connections between multiple instances the same app.

I created an example app that demonstrates how to do this which I link to and explain in great detail here: http://brendaninnis.ca/connect-nearby-devices-part-2.html

I have an example for both Android and iOS that communicate with each other.